# wmmoonclock won't display

Tags: unity

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and wanted to display the phase of the moon as a little picture on my desktop, or via the Unity Bar.  In Synaptic I found a programme called wmMoonClock and I installed this, but afterwards nothing showed on my desktop, or when searching the launcher, or typing moon or wmmoonclock at the command prompt.  How can I make it work please?  I can also see the programme in Ubuntu packages here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/x11/wmmoonclock but don't know how to proceed from there.  It is not in Ubuntu Software Centre.  Nothing much else about this programme on searching, and if it is not reliable or might crash the computer then I'd obviously avoid it!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a panel indicator; I had to add it to the items listed in **start up applications** otherwise you have to manually find the application and start it. The moon indicator I used in Trusty is here [panel indicators for Trusty](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/08/useful-panel-indicators-collection-for.html)

Comment: The Lunar-Indicator is great, thank-you.  I see it is now listed in my Synaptic so will update when needed.  When I upgrade to Ubuntu 16 in due course, will I need to reinstall it?

Comment: Best to add the PPA and install directly from the source.  Details at http://askubuntu.com/a/292529/67335.